# Where does neg store the reversed number?

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

I'm reading a book about assembly x86 on the FASM assembler and the following sentence is introduced:

> neg subtracts a signed integer operand from zero. The effect of this
>   instructon is to reverse the sign of the operand from positive to
>   negative or from negative to positive.

It subtracts the operand from `0`, so if I have 6 ,`(0-6=-6)` and if I have -6 `(0-(-6)=6)`

Now, where does it save the reversed number? In the given operand? It doesn't say anymore about it in the book, so here I am wondering what's its purpose if we can't store it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the author of the book assumed it was obvious that it was stored somewhere, and the only logical place is back into the given operand, like INC / DEC and NOT.

As you say, it wouldn't make much sense if it didn't store it anywhere.

And your book is presumably not trying to be an ISA reference manual; Intel and AMD publish those (for free as PDF) and you should consult them any time you aren't sure about something like this.

See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for links to docs.

- HTML extracts of Intel's vol.2 manual http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/, e.g. [`neg`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/neg) specifically.
- [An older extract](https://c9x.me/x86/) of Intel's manual, from before they added SSE2 or x86-64 so it's much less cluttered.  [`neg`](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_216.html) there.
- https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html Intel's official PDFs that those above HTML pages are scraped from.
- https://developer.amd.com/resources/developer-guides-manuals/.  AMD's equivalent.  Note some fun differences like AMD documenting that `bsf` / `bsr` leave the destination unmodified when the source is `0`, which Intel just does it but documents it as undefined.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Differences_between_AMD64_and_Intel_64

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the given operand. You can see that [in Intel's x86 instruction manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/neg):

> ## NEG
>
> Replaces the value of operand (the destination operand) with its two's complement. (This operation is equivalent to subtracting the operand from 0.) The destination operand is located in a general-purpose register or a memory location

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the destination is the same.

It may also be a memory location.